# AutoLayout on iPad and iPhone?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, xcode6

I'm building an app on Xcode 6 using swift and am making it only for iPhones and iPods, not for iPads. I have been told that even though you're only building an app for iPhone, Apple requires the app to run smoothly on an iPad otherwise they might reject it until you make it work on universal screen sizes. I understand auto layout pretty well but I have a question; let's say I make all my buttons, labels and elements on a compact width and regular height screen size (for all iPhones in portrait) and write my code so that it works on that screen size... would I just have to make the same buttons, labels and elements for a regular width and regular height screen size and my app would still run perfectly, or would I have to rewrite the entire code with new button outlets and element names?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any rule stating you have to make your app work on all device variations. Either way you can still programmatically adjust any view objects that may not adjust the way you like via autolayout. There are plenty of applications on the store that are strictly submitted as iPhone/iPod only.

There is also no reason you would not be able to use the same IBAction or IBOutlet code for separate layouts as well. No need to duplicate any code.

There is a caveat. If you submit a 'universal' application, and down the road decide to limit the application to iPhone only (or iPad only) you will need to submit it as a new application. Apple doesn't allow you to change this after a version has already been published.

Answer (score 0):

There are build settings for an app to only be iPhone, iPad, and Universal. It should be noted that iPhone apps can still be downloaded in iPads, they just don't appear in the same locations on the iPad App Store. If you do not not have any iPad specific setups, it simply scales the app to fit the entire screen, as opposed to doing a native iPad layout. I believe it scales up the 3.5 inch version of the app.

Autolayout is super useful and provides a ton of versatility when considering different screen sizes, which is more important now than it ever has been before.

Another tool Apple equips with us is the ability to create separate nibs for either iPhone or iPad. For example, if you have MyViewController.h, -.m, and -.xib, you can use an extension to the name so that the app loads that one for that device. The syntax is MyViewController~iphone.xib and MyViewController~ipad.xib. There's nothing you have to do programmatically or in your build settings to get this to work. Just set the name properly and make sure all the outlets are hooked up. Unless you're modifying the layout programmatically, there will be no problems, and all of your code will work just fine.

This is actually always checked if on an Universal app or an iPhone app running on an iPad - if the device is an iPad, it looks for the ~ipad version of the nib. Failing to find one, it loads the ~iphone or the only one available.